# how to add ckeditor in jsp

Tags: jsp, ckeditor

i want to add ckeditor to my jsp page but it is not working.i have already included the jar file but it still dont appear in the pages. Pages show the normal text editor Please help me out. Thanks in advance..
code:

```
<%@page import="com.ckeditor.CKEditorConfig"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form action="sample_posteddata.jsp" method="get">
            <p>
                <label for="editor1">Editor 1:</label>
                <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <%
            CKEditorConfig settings = new CKEditorConfig();
            settings.addConfigValue("width", "500");
        %>
        <ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="/ckeditor/" config="<%=settings%>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: View source in your browser and post the resulting HTML for the part you provided the JSP code for.

Comment: In the end the custom tag here should become some javascript I think.  You can also avoid using the custom JSP tag and just setup CKEditor directly in Javascript: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter